# I want to do npm install from a branch of a repository published on Github

Tags: git, github, npm, npm-install

## Installed from

https://github.com/cheddarwhizzy/strapi-plugin-import-export-content/tree/v4-migration
This is a branch called v4-migration in this repository.
I tried npm install URL# branch name.

## Current status, considerations

It is added to package.json.
But it cannot be executed.
Therefore, we think we may be doing npm install incorrectly.

```
"@strapi/import-export-content": "github:cheddarwhizzy/strapi-plugin-import-export-content#v4-migration",
```

````
├── @strapi/import-export-content@0.4.2 (git+ssh://git@github.com/cheddarwhizzy/strapi-plugin-import-export-content.git#1fbbd561317e38e3df4dd0f46369acf47b58551a)
```

It will be displayed like this.
````